# Imprimir tabela com ajax e php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Estou tentando imprimir uma tabela usando php, ajax e mysql.

**Tenho esse trecho em Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Teste Ajax</title>
<?php 
require("cabecalho.php"); 
?>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<center>
    <table border="1" width="500">
         <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Origem</th>
            <th>Papel</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody id="listateste">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#listateste').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
$.ajax({
    type:'post',        //Definimos o método HTTP usado
    dataType: 'json',   //Definimos o tipo de retorno
    url: 'puxa.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
    success: function(dados){
        for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
            //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
            $('#listateste').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].origem+'</td><td>'+dados[i].Papel+'</td><td>'+dados[i].usuario+'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
});
});
```

**E PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
include ("Conectcma.php");

$qryLista = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg_qm_papel", $conexao);   

$resultado = array();

$resultado[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryLista);

echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

Se eu retorno o array dentro do próprio PHP, a array é imprimida mas aparentemente o valor não chega no Js, tirei o mysql_fetch_assoc() do loop só pra testar, mas não fez mt diferença
Alguém sabe me dizer oq eu tô fazendo de errado?

Pelo dev tools tb não me retorna nada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No meu caso, estou com uma versão onde da erro que a função mysql está depreciada, só adicionar essa linha no inicio do seu arquivo puxa.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Apesar que não é aconselhável.
Meu response na devtools, o seu tem que ser algo assim, verifique:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu coloquei e deu erro na execução
Mas não sei se o problema é nessa parte, pois o php executa perfeitamente e me retorna o array, porêm o ajax não

Comment: Aqui funcionou normal, edite sua pergunta com o resultado do seu ajax no dev tools, ai posso ajudar melhor.

Comment: Editei lá, não retornou nada :(

Comment: Como você conseguiu ver que o PHP estava retornando o resultado do banco de maneira correta?

Comment: Executei o puxa.php com um print_r dentro e me retornou a array

Comment: Você não tem outro arquivo puxa.php em seu projeto em alguma pasta diferente? pode ser que ele está indo para outra página, porque ai realmente não faz sentido..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69517/discussion-between-arllondias-and-shinchila-matadora).